# SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-agent

I came across these two services separately running in Services.msc -

- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) - *started+Automatic*
- SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) - *Disabled*

Can you please guide why do we need SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)?

Thank you!

Comment: It's optional and, as you've said, disabled by default. It's a SQL-server-based scheduled jobs service, useful for running SQL tasks such as database clean-ups or even backups. If you're worried about the installation footprint I doubt it's much at all on top of the rest of SQL server.

Comment: @Rup, you should make that an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Giorgi beat me to it with the link, which more or less says all of that.

Comment: Dont forget that the express edition of SQL server does not have the agent function. The service is there but will not start if you try to run it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server Agent is used for running jobs: [About SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)